# VB.Net OleDBConnection code to update access database from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a simple userform with a DataGridView and I would like to use OleDB code to update the accdb database based on any entries made in the gridview. The load button works fine, but the save button produces this error: 
Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Dim myConString As String
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim Dadapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSet As DataSet
    Dim DSet2 As DataSet
    Dim ConCMD As OleDb.OleDbCommand

    Private Sub load_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles load_btn.Click

        myConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\Psmccsfs01\snd\PRODUCTION\Licensed\Reporting\FTO Adjustment Tools\FTO_Log_DB.accdb;"
        con.ConnectionString = myConString
        con.Open()
        Dadapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from FTO_Log", con)
        DSet = New DataSet
        Dadapter.Fill(DSet, "FTO_Log")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DSet.Tables("FTO_Log")
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click

        Using con = New OleDbConnection(myConString)
            con.Open()
            Dadapter.Update(DSet, "FTO_Log")
        End Using

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: for one thing, `Dadapter` and `DSet` will be `Nothing` in the save procedure unless the user has already clicked the load button. The error is telling you that you havent provided the SQL Update command.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am very new to this, so is there any way you could show me how the save_btn code would look?

Comment: actually, save may need to address 2 conditions: INSERTing a new record and UPDATEing an existing one.  You need to add SQL statements for those and also DELETE if you will be doing that too.  MSDN has examples for all of them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still very new to this, so would it be possible to modify my code to show me how it would look? I am lost when I look at that link.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataAdpater.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(
           "UPDATE Categories SET CategoryName = @CategoryName " +
           "WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID", connection);
```

notice the typo in the code above, straight from the msdn site ;p

short and simple: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks porkchop, but I am having trouble adapting that to my code without errors. I tried:

        Dadapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(
           "UPDATE Categories SET CategoryName = @CategoryName " +
           "WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID", con);

Error: Sql command cannot be converted to OleDb Command

Comment: oh, my apologies. i don't usually work wil OleDB, but you will need another set of statements and commands (also, don't just type that in, it has to match your database records) plutonix already posted this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx